# iMac shows prohibitory symbol

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I recently booted up my iMac, but then the Apple logo disappeared and a replaced it. I tried going into Recovery mode but recovery mode just takes LITERALLY hours. No matter how long I let it load, recovery mode doesn't help: I let it load overnight and it still didn't work.

How can I fix this issue and boot into my iMac again?

[image]

Comment: What is the "prohibitory" symbol? Comment back `@owlswipe` with more detail and I'll reopen this question.

Comment: @owlswipe my screen loads and then stops. It then shows a circle with a line 

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211152/prohibitory-sign-showing-on-mac-startup, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240324/troubleshooting-apple-booting-to-prohibitory-sign, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119597/boot-up-error-prohibitory-sign-flashing-folder-with-question-mark

Comment: Hi @marigold - are you looking for someone to say use an external recovery media or perhaps a link to how to make recovery media? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119600/5472

Answer (score 1):

This happen to me too after I started and then canceled the installation of Mojave.

I fixed it easily by following these steps.

1. Boot in recovery by Powering up and immediately holding CMD+R
2. Clicked on Apple logo and choose Startup Disk
3. Select the Mac OS disk and click restart.

If these steps didn't work then you can try reset. 
**WARNING this will delete all your Files**

1. Select Disk util from the recovery menu
2. Erase Disk
3. Go back and Reinstall OS

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to outline the steps to take. If your internal recovery fails, use an external recovery disk.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202294

If that fails or you can't accomplish it, seek hardware service or someone that has the tools to make an external drive with a bootable OS.